# Count colored cells by conditional formatting (greater than/lesser than)

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I have columns that are formatted by the conditional formatting GREATER THAN / LESSER THAN. I want to have a function that takes the range and a referenced cell.

I tried several UDFs from the net that either doesnt count any color or count every conditionally colored cell not the referenced cell whose color should be counted. For Example:

```
Function COUNTConditionColorCells(CellsRange As Range, ColorRng As Range)
    Dim Bambo As Boolean
    Dim dbw As String
    Dim CFCELL As Range
    Dim CF1 As Single
    Dim CF2 As Double
    Dim CF3 As Long

    Bambo = False

    For CF1 = 1 To CellsRange.FormatConditions.Count
        If CellsRange.FormatConditions(CF1).Interior.ColorIndex = ColorRng.Interior.ColorIndex Then
            Bambo = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next CF1

    CF2 = 0
    CF3 = 0

    If Bambo = True Then
        For Each CFCELL In CellsRange
            dbw = CFCELL.FormatConditions(CF1).Formula1
            dbw = Application.ConvertFormula(dbw, xlA1, xlR1C1)
            dbw = Application.ConvertFormula(dbw, xlR1C1, xlA1, , ActiveCell.Resize(CellsRange.Rows.Count, CellsRange.Columns.Count).Cells(CF3 + 1))

            If Evaluate(dbw) = True Then CF2 = CF2 + 1

            CF3 = CF3 + 1
        Next CFCELL
    Else
        COUNTConditionColorCells = "NO-COLOR"
        Exit Function
    End If

    COUNTConditionColorCells = CF2
End Function
```

This UDF gives me NO-COLOR. I think that the color cant be detected, but what else can I do? Any ideas?

Comment: Instead of using a UDF, use a formula with the logic you use for the conditional formatting.

Comment: And please indent your code to make it more readable and easier to debug.

Comment: [Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com/Indentation) has an indented to help you with that

Answer (score 0):

I have an app that does some funky things with colouring.  I wrote this bit to check to see if I had already looked after a row or not.  The key bit of code is:

```
sht.Cells(theRow, theColumn).Select    

If Selection.Interior.Color = eYellow Or Selection.Interior.Color = eGreen Then 'make sure we're not overwriting a row.
    Stop
End If
```

Where I had previously defined eYellow and eGreen..

```
Private Const eYellow As Long = rgbYellow
Private Const eGreen As Long = rgbLightGreen
```

The tricky part is I was only able to get the check to work if I selected the cell in question first.

I think what's happening is that your if statement isn't being satisfied because you're checking the wrong property. What if you try without **.FormatConditions(CF1)**?  Maybe this will simplify your check enough to get it to work?